# c++ - Undefined Reference to Existing Function

Tags: c++, linker

Alright, I'm developing a small network library to use in another application of mine. I've got a function declared in NetStream.h like so:

```
class NetStream;
class NetStream {
public:
  static NetStream *connect(char *ip, char *port, char** error);
  ...
}
```

In my NetStream.cpp, I've got it defined with the same prototype:

```
NetStream* NetStream::connect(char *ip, char *port, char** error) {
  ...
}
```

When I objdump my libNetLib.a, I can see that NetStream::connect is defined:

```
$ objdump -Ct NetLib/libNetLib.a | grep 'connect' #demangled names
000000000000031a g     F .text  00000000000001b4 NetStream::connect(char*, char*, char**)
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 connect

$ objdump -t NetLib/libNetLib.a | grep 'connect' #mangled names
000000000000031a g     F .text  00000000000001b4 _ZN9NetStream7connectEPcS0_PS0
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 connect
```

In a the object file in the application that uses my NetLib, objdump reveals that it's importing a function with the same prototype:

```
$ objdump -Ct connection.cpp.o | grep 'connect'
...
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 NetStream::connect(char*, char*, char**)
...

$ objdump -t connection.cpp.o | grep 'connect'
...
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZN9NetStream7connectEPcS0_PS0_
...
```

But when I link the application with g++ `4.9.2`, I get this error:

```
connection.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `NetStream::connect(char*, char*, char**)'
```

This happens when CMake tries to link it, and when I link it with the following command:

```
$ g++ connection.cpp.o -L NetStream.cpp.o -o /tmp/tst
```

I get the same undefined reference (and a bunch of other undefined references because there's other things to be linked in, too, that I didn't link there).

I've looked around a bit and seen that this is usually caused when const pointers in function prototypes differ, but there's no const here.

What's the *real* problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to look up the meaning of command line options for g++, because you are badly misusing them.

-L*directory* tells the linker to look in *directory* for library files.  Unless you have a directory named "NetStream.cpp.o" (which is pretty unlikely) and you specify libraries in that directory to link (which you haven't) your command line is gibberish.

Your command line is effectively telling the linker to look in a directory for library files, but not giving any information about libraries to be linked against.   So your "NetLib.a" is not even accessed by the linker.

Assuming you have a library named NetLib.a in a directory (relative to the working directory when g++ is invoked) named NetLib then -  as Employed Russian has pointed out -  you either need to do "g++ connection.cpp.o -LNetLib -lNetLib -o /tmp/tst" to link against the library or "g++ connection.cpp.o NetLib/libNetLib.a -o /tmp/tst".

Answer (score 3):

> `g++ connection.cpp.o -L NetStream.cpp.o -o /tmp/tst`

This command line is completely bogus. Try this instead:

```
g++ connection.cpp.o -LNetLib -lNetLib -o /tmp/tst
```

or this:

```
g++ connection.cpp.o NetLib/libNetLib.a -o /tmp/tst
```

**Update:**

> What is the *real* problem here?

The *real* problem is that your link command line is incorrect (as stated above).

> I can't really compile my code like that ...

Compilation is not the problem here, linking is.

Presumably you can't construct correct link command because you are using `CMake`, and it is `CMake` that constructs bogus link command line.

Since we *know* that `CMake` works, we must assume that it is your `CMakefile` that is the root cause. Unfortunately, you haven't shown your `CMakefile`.

You should ask a separate question, like this: "I have the following `CMakefile`, which results in the following link line, which this answer tells me is bogus. What is wrong with my `CMakefile`?"

Comment: How come that makes a difference? Yes, it *works*, but I can't really compile my code like that and it doesn't answer the question: 'What is the *real* problem here'

Comment: That link line was just something I was using to test if CMake was being problematic. I constructed it, so that's probably why it didn't really work. As Peter said, I really need to look up g++ command line usage. Of course, if my test returns a false negative, that leads me to falsely believe that CMake is working fine. But, because it works when I adjust my command line, that means that CMake was the problem. Turns out that CMake was just not linking NetLib in for some reason. It's fixed now

Comment: @Xenotoad I didn't realize that "this link command is completely bogus" was not a sufficient clue for you to look at the man page and to understand why that is so; and that you needed a detailed explanation of that.